# css before and after used with every div with display table

Tags: css

I am a beginner so I was inspecting some websites source code and I have noticed some of them uses

```
::before{
content = "";
display : table;
table-layout : fixed;
} and  

::after {

content = "";
display : table;
table-layout : fixed;

}
```

both with most of the div tags and I tried to understand but could not get it if anyone uses this please tell me its use

Answer (score -1):

Before after is the CSS pseudo element.

**::before** selector is used for insert something **before** the content of each selected element.

**::after** selector is used for insert something **after** the content of each selected element.

for more information and example please check this below site.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/